# SQL Server AVG and Excel AVERAGE producing different results?

Tags: sql-server, excel, average

I'm trying to show averages on SQL server, but when I test the data in Excel the results are not the same, there must be something obvious I am missing.

Here is the code and results from SQL server:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
d.d_reference + ' - ' + d.d_name AS Faculty,
AVG(sub.GroupSize) AS FacultyAverage


FROM
unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_register r
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr ON sr.sr_register = r.r_id
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_activity a ON a.a_register = r.r_id
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_moduleactivity ma ON ma.ma_activity = a.a_id
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_module m ON m.m_id = ma.ma_activitymodule
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_department d ON d.d_id = m.m_moduledept
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_section sec ON sec.s_id = m.m_modulesection
INNER JOIN (SELECT
            r.r_reference,
            COUNT(DISTINCT s.s_studentreference) AS GroupSize
            FROM
            unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_student s
            INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_person p ON p.p_id = s.s_id
            INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr ON sr.sr_student = p.p_id
            INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_register r ON r.r_id = sr.sr_register
            GROUP BY
            r.r_reference) sub ON sub.r_reference = r.r_reference

WHERE
SUBSTRING(r.r_reference,4,2) = '12' AND
d.d_reference = '730'

GROUP BY
d.d_reference,
d.d_name
```

[image]

Here is the results in Excel:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this for fun:

```
select avg(a)
from
    (values(1),(2),(3),(4)) x(a);

avg(a)
-------
2
```

AVG() returns the same datatype as the base column.  If your columns are of type *int*, then the result will be truncated to an *int* as well.  The below returns the "correct" result.

```
select avg(cast(a as decimal(10,5)))
from
    (values(1),(2),(3),(4)) x(a);

result
--------
2.5
```

The discrepancy you are showing (24 vs 19.50484) will most likely involve another error in conjunction with this.  For example, to check that you are summing up the same data in Excel as in SQL Server, dump this result into Excel and sum it up.  If it doesn't match what you currently believe is the Excel ***equivalent*** of the SQL Server data, line the columns up and check they have the same number of rows. Then sort each column individually by value ASCENDING and compare again.

```
SELECT d.d_name, sub.GroupSize AS FacultyAverage
FROM unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_register r
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr ON sr.sr_register = r.r_id
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_activity a ON a.a_register = r.r_id
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_moduleactivity ma ON ma.ma_activity = a.a_id
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_module m ON m.m_id = ma.ma_activitymodule
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_department d ON d.d_id = m.m_moduledept
INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_section sec ON sec.s_id = m.m_modulesection
INNER JOIN (SELECT r.r_reference,
            COUNT(DISTINCT s.s_studentreference) AS GroupSize
            FROM unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_student s
            INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_person p ON p.p_id = s.s_id
            INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_studentregister sr ON sr.sr_student = p.p_id
            INNER JOIN unitesnapshot.dbo.capd_register r ON r.r_id = sr.sr_register
            GROUP BY r.r_reference) sub ON sub.r_reference = r.r_reference
WHERE SUBSTRING(r.r_reference,4,2) = '12' AND d.d_reference = '730'
ORDER BY d.d_name
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer Richard, but I just tried this and it doesnt work, it just produces a decimal result of 24.412407? any ideas?

Comment: I was highlighting the fact that Excel's AVERAGE produces a real (floating point) number but SQL Server will follow the type of the base column. I already commented that you have other issues. Without showing all your data, there's no way to check. There're so many ways to make errors copying data from SQL Server to Excel.

Comment: Thanks, the excel data is produced from a slight variation of the query in my original question, so the data should be the accurate.

Comment: When I do SUM(sub.GroupSize) AS FacultyAverage i get 2385556 but in excel the sumn shows 24186, this suggests there ius something wrong with the query righ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for your help, I will backtrack through the data and find the issue, I just thought it may be a problem with the query.

Comment: What I would suggest is that you take up my last point in the answer about doing some basic debugging and data matching. List out the individual rows from the SQL Server query, then compare them to what you have in Excel, filtered if necessary.

Comment: It may well be a problem with the query in that it is not producing the right rows to perform the aggregate AVG/SUM against, but that's where your closer inspection of the data comes in.